# SQL Server: after converting from image to varbinary(MAX), should I update the converted column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 200GB table with a column of type `image`, which I'm planing to convert to a `varbinary(MAX)`. After reading this post about converting `NTEXT` http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx the writer suggest to do an

```
UPDATE testTable 
SET testText = testText
```

After the conversion. Can the same be applied to a conversion between `image` and `varbinary`?

Comment: Should be fine -- do a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this command

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
ALTER COLUMN YourImageColumn VARBINARY(MAX);
```

and that should take care of everything.

There's no extra "conversion" step needed at all.

But again: **do this on a TEST instance** first!

And before you do it on your live system, ***TAKE A BACKUP!***

You've been warned! :-)